# ng-animate ng-repeat not working lasted version AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I found this example of ng-animate. But it does not work in my application on AngularJS 1.2-1.3
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jgoemat/kta95/1/

What am I doing wrong?
thx

upd: I found this: 
 http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html 
its bad for me =(

Comment: It si working with last angular stable version 1.2.15 http://fiddle.jshell.net/kta95/45/

Comment: rly? i cant see animation!